# Need help using continue functions in python for an UNO card game

Tags: python

I'm coding an UNO game with python and I can't figure out how to code the game so that when the computer skips the user's turn, it goes back to the computer's turn.

Right now I'm using the continue function after the computer plays a skip, but the problem is that it still allows the computer to go to the top of the loop and play a one card (yellow 1, etc), because that matches what the user played before. Instead, it should be only allowed to play a red card. How can I use continue to only allow the computer to play a red card?

```
 for i in computer_deck:
    if(i in one_cards):
        print(i)
        break 
    elif(i in red_cards):
        computer_play = i
        print(computer_play)
        computer_cards = computer_cards - 1

      if(computer_play in skip_cards):
        user_turn == computer_play
        print("My turn again: ")
        print("")
        continue
    else:
      print("Draw")
```

Comment: Are you sure this line 'user_turn == computer_play' does what you want it to do?

Comment: I did that because the line before that code is if user_turn == cards[0]:. Cards[0] is red 1. It still works if I delete the line but the problem is the same

Comment: As mentioned in the answer by... erm... in the answer below: == is for comparison, it will always return a boolean value (True or False), whereas = is used for assignments.

Comment: You don't have to wrap conditions in brackets, you can just do `if i in one_cards:`

Comment: I think maybe if you can describe the problem better we can reconstruct another piece of code instead of fixing this.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I'll try to explain the problem in a different way: I'm looking for a way to avoid the "if i in one_cards" clause when the computer plays a skip. It should only be able to play a red card, so I think it would work if the code looped it back to the "elif i in red_cards" clause.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding correctly, I tried to fix some issues and I thought maybe just adding a boolean variable to check if the computer skipped then they cannot play a yellow card even if continue takes them back to the top.

```
skipped_turn = False 
for i in computer_deck:
    if(i in one_cards and not skipped_turn): #Yellow card?
        print(i)
        skipped_turn = False
        break 
    elif(i in red_cards):
        computer_play = i
        print(computer_play)
        computer_cards = computer_cards - 1
        skipped_turn = False

    elif(computer_play in skip_cards): #Following the same if statements and not ran if the others are selected 
        user_turn = computer_play #Assigning the user's turn '==' is for comparison 
        print("My turn again: ")
        skipped_turn = True
        continue
   else:
      print("Draw")
```

Comment: Yes I did thanks. Is there a way to do it without the spaces?

Comment: @ウィエム you can use a triple back tick ``` to make coding blocks as well, just put the code between 2 triple back ticks